# How can I calculate the Fourier transformation of a function if I know the outcome of another fourier transformation?

Tags: fourier-analysis

So I have the function $$f:f(t)=\frac{4}{t^2+9}$$ and I know that

\begin{align*}
\mathcal{F}\{e^{-|t|}\}(\omega) 
&= \frac{2}{\omega^2+1}.
\end{align*}

I'd gotten proof of the latter Fourier Transformation in another question thread, but whenever I try to compute the earlier function with fourier transformation, it seems very hard to do at its current form. Wolfram Alpha can do it just fine, but computing it with a calculator just won't do.

Comment: Hint: Use Duality theorem of frequency and time domain.

Comment: Does switching from f(t) to f(w) entail something other than simply switching t into w, or have I missed something in regards from transforming a function from time-level to frequency-level?

Comment: There is this relation: $$f(t) \rightarrow F(\omega)$$ $$F(t) \rightarrow 2\pi f(-\omega)$$. And proof of it is quite simple.

Comment: Is it a "Fourier transformation" if I make $F(t)$, or do I have to process it further down the line?

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
g(t) := \frac{2}{t^2+1}
$$
In [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2154267/how-can-i-fourier-transform-this-function-with-a-special-character-inside/2154284#2154284) to a previous question of yours, it was shown, using the inversion theorem, that
$$
\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{2}{t^2+1}\right\}(\omega) = 2\pi e^{-|\omega|}
$$
Now note that $f(t) = \frac{2}{9} g(t/3)$ and recall the following result.

> **Proposition:** If $f(t) = g(at)$ where $a \in \Bbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$ then $$\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega) = \frac{1}{|a|}\mathcal{F}\{g\}(\omega/a)$$

Thus
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}\{f\}(\omega) &= \frac{2}{9}\cdot\left(3\cdot2\pi e^{-|3\omega|}\right)\\
&=\frac{4\pi}{3}e^{-3|\omega|}
\end{align}